# SQL not inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Alright, so I've been rewriting a bunch of code for my site over the past couple of days, and for some reason, one specific code is not inserting properly:

The code (which i've posted below) fires perfectly if I remove the where clauses. The code has fired before, and continues to fire in the old version of the code (Which i'll post if needed, but seeing as the SQL pretty much is exactly the same, i don't see that being the issue).

```
function starMap()
{
    $x =$this->randomCoords();
    $y = $this->randomCoords();
    $px = mt_rand($this->limit_low, $this->limit_high);
    $py = mt_rand($this->limit_low, $this->limit_high);
    $sql = 
    "INSERT IGNORE INTO starinformation 
    (starOwner,  
     underSiege, 
     pageX, 
     pageY, 
     coordX, 
     coordY,
     resourceArray)
     values
     (0, 0, :pX, :pY, :cY, :cX, :r)
     WHERE 
        (coordX != {$x} AND coordY != {$y})
        OR
        (coordX != {$x}-5 AND coordY != {$y}-5)
        OR
        (coordX != {$x}+5 AND coordY != {$y}+5)
        AND
        pageX = {$px} AND pageY = {$py} 
     ;";
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO system_buildings(starID) VALUES (null);";
    $num = mt_rand($this->limit_low,$this->limit_high);
    $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $que->bindParam(':cY', $y);
    $que->bindParam(':cX', $x);
    $que->bindParam(':pY', $py);
    $que->bindParam(':pX', $px);
    $que->bindParam(':r', $num);
    try { 
    $que->execute();
         }catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getCode().'|'.$e->getMessage();
            }
    $id =$this->db->lastInsertId();
    return $id;

}
```

Comment: Can you try running the query NOT through PHP? Then you can begin to narrow down if the problem is with the query itself or with the PHP code that is using it.

Comment: I've run it through the phpMyAdmin system, and it just says there's an issue near "WHERE..."

Comment: The person below told you. INSERT does not have a `where` clause. Here, read it for yourself http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html `INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)] 
    [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name=expr
        [, col_name=expr] ... ]` and other examples. Use `update` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html instead to use a `where` clause.

Comment: ^^ now do you believe them/me?

Comment: I understand that the person below me told me that the INSERT doesn't support WHERE, however it doesn't fix my issue. As i've done exactly what they told me to do and still cannot insert the information i'm trying to insert.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` syntax cannot have `WHERE` clause. The only time you will find `INSERT` has `WHERE` clause is when you are using `INSERT INTO...SELECT` statement.

An example of it:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM Suppliers;
```

it will insert every record (columns `SupplierName` and `Country`) in `Supplier` into Customers

if you dont believe me you can see it with your own eyes [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=insert%20where%20clause&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: Ah -- only time i've heard that expression is when people are being pricks. lol I'm still at a loss as to why the code worked in my previous version of the code, only thing I can guess is its because i called a SELECT query in the same line (different query but it was all executed at the same time)

Comment: I am not smart enough to be a smart a*s. I t was just a unfortunate expression (maybe 'cause English is not my first language) However; I think your previous version was combined the two queries as one and treat it as I showed you on my answer.